# Socket.io is connecting/creating 2 clients when it should be connecting 1

Tags: javascript, socket.io, multiplayer

So I'm making a basic multiplayer game (my first multiplayer game)
just started on it, this is the code that I have for the socket.io connection

when 1 player connects to the server (opens localhost:3000) it creates 2 players, 2 Ids, and everything. Basically, it thinks 2 sockets are connected to 1 only. Also important to note when 1 player leaves, it removes itself and removes the extra socket that was made with it, this obviously causes a lot of problems.

````
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 10000) + 10000);
  client_list[client.id] = client;

  let player = new Player(client.id)
  player_list[client.id] = player;

  client.emit('init', client.id)
  console.log(client.id + ' connected')

  client.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log(client.id + ' disconnected')
      delete client_list[client.id]
      delete player_list[client.id]
  });
});```
````

Comment: why are you overwriting socket.id with random number?

Comment: socket.id isnt anything right? im just defining socket.id with a random 5 digit number to keep track of it

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/#socketid